# Error with running Python executable from script.py

Tags: python, python-2.7, cx-freeze

I created an executable `.exe` from a `.py` file using the latest version of [cx_freeze](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) for Python 2.7 with the following **`setup.py`** file:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup(
    name = "Any",
    version = "1.0",
    description = "Any",
    executables = [Executable("D:\\script.pyw", base = "Win32GUI")])
```

I ran it from command line:

```
python setup.py build
```

Then I got the executable file in the build directory as expected. It ran perfectly.

Now, If I move the executable file into a different directory on the same computer. I get the following error dialog:

[image]

My guess is that I need to embed something into the executable file to make it work not only on my computer but on any other computer where Python is not installed by changing something in the **`setup.py`** file. What could be it missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am building compiled executable as follows.

Using following versions:

```
OS: Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1
Python: 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
cx_Freeze: 4.2.3
```

I have this code `hello_tkinter.py`:

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk

class Main(Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.frame = ttk.Frame(self)
        self.frame.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.button = ttk.Button(self.frame, text="Test")
        self.button.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)

root = Main()
root.mainloop()
```

I call this script installed with `cx_freeze`:

```
c:\Python27\Scripts\cxfreeze.bat hello_tkinter.py --target-dir=Bin/tkinter --base-name=Win32GUI --target-name=hello_tkinter.exe
```

And I get the directory containing:

```
tcl\
tk\
_ctypes.pyd
_tkinter.pyd
bz2.pyd
hello_tkinter.exe
MSVCR90.dll
python27.dll
tcl85.dll
tk85.dll
unicodedata.pyd
```

It works fine and even if I move the directory. You did take the whole directory, not just the exe, did not you? The executable was also tested on Windows XP without Python installed.

Comment: I just took the executable in my case and it didn't work. should it not? If not then can it create just one single executable? What will be it's average size?

Comment: No, it should not. There are dynamic libraries linked etc. Single executable is neither possible in `cx_freeze`, nor recommended packaging for Python. In Python 2.7 `py2exe` and `pyinstaller` can do it. Anyway, all libraries which can do it use hacks to achieve it and antivirus programs may be very suspicious of the way how your exe will unpack when you run it. Your one-exe-packs-all may load very slow for that reason on some systems. I always encourage packing cx_freeze output directory using Inno setup to create Windows installer.